# Is it possible reboot system when windows is in lock screen?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an ASP Core application that host a gRPC service. This service receive some commands. One of the it is reboot the system.

This ASP service is run at startup when a normal user, not an administrator user, starts the session. This user start the session when the system starts.

When the user is log in, the reboot command works fine, but if I enter with remote deskop and exit with the X, I don't close session, just I disconnect, the user session is still open, but the computer go to the lock screen. In this case, the reboot command doesn't work. But the service is still running, because I can ping it.

So my question is if it is possible to reboot the computer when the system is in the lock screen.

This is the code that I use to reboot the system:

```
public void Reboot()
{
    ProcessStartInfo miProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    miProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "/r /t 0 /soft";
    miProcessStartInfo.FileName = "shutdown";
    miProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    miProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    miProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    using (Process? miProceso = Process.Start(miProcessStartInfo))
    {
        if (miProceso == null)
        {
            throw GetRpcException($"Error indeterminado al interntar ejecutar la acción {paramNombreAccion} de la aplicación {paramNombreAplicacion}.");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `/soft` is probably letting running applications prevent shutdown. Remove that option to force a shutdown. You could also use WINAPI functions directly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdownexw

Comment: I have tried to use these arguments and it works: /r /f /t 0. With /f it forces to reboot the system.